# How to supply list parameter for SOAP

Tags: c#, soap

I'm not able to supply input parameter for following response list
 structure pls advise how it can be achieved

```
this is my c# code


Supcancel.supplyCancelServiceRequest sup = new Supcancel.supplyCancelServiceRequest();


   Supcancel.product prd = new Supcancel.product();
   prd.BN = "004";
   prd.GTIN = "06102030405089";
   prd.SN = "29091576";
   prd.XD = xd_date;

sup.PRODUCTLIST[0].BN = "004";
sup.PRODUCTLIST[1].GTIN = "06102030405089";
sup.PRODUCTLIST[2].SN = "29091576";
sup.PRODUCTLIST[3].XD = xd_date;


   var cn = cclient.notifySupplyCancel(sup);
```

This is the request format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      <SupplyCancelServiceRequest xmlns="http://dtts.sfda.gov.sa/SupplyCancelService">
            <PRODUCTLIST xmlns="">
                <PRODUCT>
                    <GTIN>[string]</GTIN>
                    <SN>[string]</SN>
                    <BN>[string?]</BN>
                    <XD>[date?]</XD>
                </PRODUCT>
            </PRODUCTLIST>
        </SupplyCancelServiceRequest>
```

Comment: See following : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/764496/Invoke-a-POST-method-with-XML-Request-message-in-C

Comment: What does the xsd (wsdl) look like?